# Matlab hangs if an undefined variable is requested

Tags: windows, matlab

If I open Matlab with a clear workspace and enter

```
a
```

in the command window to return variable a, even though it does not exist, then Matlab will be 'Busy' for about 20 seconds before it tells me that the variable is undefined. During this period I cannot interrupt the process with ctrl+C.

If I enter

```
tic; a; toc
```

Then the error shows up immediately.

If I enter

```
a
```

in a new script with an empty workspace, the error shows up immediately as well. However, in some larger scripts, Matlab will hang before giving the error, just like when the variable is requested from the command window.

I considered that it could be a licensing problem but I verified that license.dat is placed correctly in the licenses folder. 
The problem exists in both Matlab 2017b and 2018a. I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1709, 64 bit. I did not have this problem on Windows 8 on the same system. Both Windows 10 and Matlab were freshly installed on the system.

How can I solve this problem and ensure that Matlab returns an error immediately, instead of getting stuck for 20 seconds?

Comment: Hi Max and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately I can not reproduce this on Windows 7 (tested with R2017b and R2018a). Have you tried contacting Mathworks Support about this? It sounds a lot like a software bug.

Comment: I cannot recreate it on R2018 either. How many directories is in your search path? Run e.g. `length(strsplit(path,':'))`

Comment: @NickyMattsson 604 directories; no idea if that is relatively large.

Comment: Not really. I think you should follow the advice by @hbaderts and contact Mathworks or the good old uninstall, install.

Comment: Thanks, I have contacted Mathworks, will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Mathworks and the solution was to empty my preferences folder. This solved it. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: What is the preferences folder? Is it `~/.matlab/<version>/`?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen for many reason , When you type a name in command windows, MATLAB behaves with this name in two ways,

**1)** it is name of variable, so it searches workspace for this variable.

**2)** it is name of function or script, so it searches all path in `PATH` of MATLAB. As we know, there are many folder in `PATH` of MATLAB, therefore it takes very much time to search all folders.

You can increase the speed by removing unnecessary path from `PATH` of MATLAB.

Comment: But given that this does not happen to the rest of us, who have just as many directories in the path, and it doesn't happen to OP when typing `tic; a; toc`, but it does when typing `a`, we can conclude that this is not a `PATH` issue.